# How to get the actual Windows login username and not the username added in Credential Manager?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, webforms

I'm currently using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to get the user's username but that returns the username that is added as a Windows credential using Credential Manager. I'm looking to get the user's own username that he/she used to login to his/her computer.

I tried Googling it but I can't find the answer I need. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: If I understand your question, How about Environment.UserName ?

Comment: @Jze That gives me the username added through Credential Manager as well.